# Add a watcher to document.title in Nuxt.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js and added different titles for different pages.

There is a component that appears in all the pages and I wanted to access the `document.title` there.

In common Component:

```
console.log(document.title) // Always comes the same one when the page loaded
```

When I change the route, I wanted to get the new title there.

Is there any way I can access the meta title in `this.$router`, `this.$meta` or able to watch the `document.title` whenever the URL changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nuxt.js @ v2.13.1

There is currently no way to listen for title updates via the $router object.

Working variant https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

You need to subscribe to update the DOM element.

In the main layout:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    title: null
  }),
  // or created() hook, if it's not SSR
  mounted() {
    this.title = document.title
    new MutationObserver(() => {
      this.title = document.title
    }).observe(document.querySelector('title'), { childList: true })
  }
}
</script>
```